# Visual Basic project that doesn't update the password value when using a form to reset the password, using a reset key word defined by the user

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, .net-4.8, sqlite.net

This code is supposed to check if the username and reset keyword match and the enable 2 textboxes and when the users inputs text and click the button it send a SQLite command and updates the password value on the database, but for some reason when the button is clicked it does nothing and even whit the try catch i doesn't show any errors

Here is the code:

```
Imports System.Data.SQLite
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text

Public Class resetar_pass
    Dim hash_reset As String
    Dim encriptacao_SHA512 As SHA512 = SHA512.Create()

    Private Sub resetar_pass_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Public Sub encriptar_reset()
        Dim valor_do_hash_reset As Byte() = encriptacao_SHA512.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TextBox1.Text))
        hash_reset = Convert.ToBase64String(valor_do_hash_reset)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Using connection As New SQLiteConnection(connectionString)
            connection.Open()

            Try
                    encriptar_reset()

                    If TextBox2.Text = TextBox3.Text Then
                    Dim resetar As String = $"UPDATE login SET password = '{TextBox3.Text}' WHERE       username = '{UsernameTextBox.Text}' AND reset = '{hash_reset}';"
                    Dim reset As New SQLiteCommand(resetar, connection)
                    reset.ExecuteNonQuery()


                Else
                        MessageBox.Show("As passwords não coicidem!")
                    End If

                Catch ex As SQLiteException
                    MessageBox.Show($"Erro ao atualizar password: {ex.Message} (Error code: {ex.ErrorCode})")


                End Try

            End Using

    End Sub

    Private Sub verificar(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseClick
        Using connection As New SQLiteConnection(connectionString)
            connection.Open()
            encriptar_reset()
            Dim reset_pass As String = $"SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '{UsernameTextBox.Text}' AND reset = '{hash_reset}';"
            Dim login_command As New SQLiteCommand(reset_pass, connection)

            Dim reader As SQLiteDataReader = login_command.ExecuteReader()

            If reader.HasRows Then
                TextBox2.Visible = True
                TextBox3.Visible = True
                connection.Close()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("O nome de utilizador ou a password está errada!")
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

I tried closing the connection here

```
Private Sub verificar(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseClick
        Using connection As New SQLiteConnection(connectionString)
            connection.Open()
            encriptar_reset()
            Dim reset_pass As String = $"SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '{UsernameTextBox.Text}' AND reset = '{hash_reset}';"
            Dim login_command As New SQLiteCommand(reset_pass, connection)

            Dim reader As SQLiteDataReader = login_command.ExecuteReader()

            If reader.HasRows Then
                TextBox2.Visible = True
                TextBox3.Visible = True
                --> connection.Close()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("O nome de utilizador ou a password está errada!")
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub
```

and used a try catch to check for errors that SQLite might send but it doesn't show anything

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Using connection As New SQLiteConnection(connectionString)
            connection.Open()

            Try
                    encriptar_reset()

                    If TextBox2.Text = TextBox3.Text Then
                    Dim resetar As String = $"UPDATE login SET password = '{TextBox3.Text}' WHERE       username = '{UsernameTextBox.Text}' AND reset = '{hash_reset}';"
                    Dim reset As New SQLiteCommand(resetar, connection)
                    reset.ExecuteNonQuery()


                Else
                        MessageBox.Show("As passwords não coicidem!")
                    End If

                Catch ex As SQLiteException
                    MessageBox.Show($"Erro ao atualizar password: {ex.Message} (Error code: {ex.ErrorCode})")


                End Try

            End Using

    End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't do nothing. The fact that the end result is not what you expect does not mean that it's doing nothing. You need to debug your code to find what it actually is doing. If you don't know how to debug, stop what you're doing and learn. It is a required skill for all developers and debugging your code is something you must do before posting a question here. One of the specific reasons for closing a question is that debugging information has not been provided, which is why your question will likely be closed.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that there are no records in the database that match your filter. `ExecuteNonQuery` returns a numbers to indicate how many records were affected. If that number is zero, the operation succeeded but there were no matching records. That is likely what your code is actually doing but you haven't even checked that return value by the looks of it.

Comment: Also, you should immediately learn how to use parameters in ADO.NET code and stop inserting variables directly into SQL code. Among other issues, it can be a security issue, potentially allowing a malicious user to corrupt or delete all your data. [Here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html) is my take on the subject.